# Как правильно реализовать наследование агрегированных классов?

Tags: c++, наследование, qt4

Это базовые классы:

```
class Foo {};
class Bar
{
    QList<Foo> fooList;
    //функции для работы с fooList;
};
```

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было написать классы наследники

```
class FooEx : public Foo {};
class BarEx : public Bar {};
class FooExList : QList<FooEx> {};
```

и при этом в BarEx тип поля fooList заменить с

```
QList<Foo> fooList
```

на

```
FooExList fooList?
```

Никак не могу найти красивое решение.

Answer (score 3):

Можно переопределить в классе-наследнике переменную-член базового класса и использовать виртуальные функции. Приведённый ниже код иллюстрирует идею и доказывает её работоспособность:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A {
    public :
        virtual void whoAmI() const {
            printf("class A.\n");
        }
};

class A1 : public A {
    public :
        virtual void whoAmI() const {
            printf("class A1.\n");
        }
};

class B {
    private :
        A a;
    public :
        virtual void whoAmI() const {
            printf("I am class B  with member of ");
            a.whoAmI();
        }
};

class B1 : public B {
    private :
        A1 a;
    public :
        virtual void whoAmI() const {
            printf("I am class B1 with member of ");
            a.whoAmI();
        }
};


int main() {
    B b;
    B1 b1;
    B* pb = new B;
    B* pb1 = new B1;

    b.whoAmI();
    b1.whoAmI();
    pb->whoAmI();
    pb1->whoAmI();

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
I am class B  with member of class A.
I am class B1 with member of class A1.
I am class B  with member of class A.
I am class B1 with member of class A1.
```

**Дополнение**

Можно ещё поступить следующим образом. Хранить в классе `Bar` не сам объект, а указатель на объект базового класса и в производных классах `BarEx` создавать объект требуемого класса:

```
class Bar {
    protected :
        QList<Foo> *pFooList = nullptr;
        Bar(QList<Foo>* _pFooList) : pFooList(_pFooList) { }
    public :
        Bar() : pFooList(new QList<Foo>()) { }
}

class BarEx {
    public :
        BarEx() : Bar(new FooExList()) { }
}
```

Недостаток этого метода в том, что в производных классах указатель `pFooList` будет иметь тип указателя на базовый класс. Но это легко решается приведением типов.

Comment: И на каждую функцию в B придется писать такую же в B1?

Comment: @GrieVeR-13 Да. У Вас, как верно заметила Mira, изначально очень странная постановка задачи. Поэтому возникают большие накладные расходы на её решение.

Answer (score 1):

В производном классе объявите переменную с тем же именем, но другим типом.

```
   class BarEx : public Bar {
        FooExList fooList

    }
```

Она перекроет родительскую переменную.

Comment: Но так же получится две разных переменных и через функции в классе Bar я не буду менять FooExList fooList в классе BarEx

Comment: @GrieVeR-13 Используй силу виртуальных функций, Люк!

Comment: Если вы в базовом классе не хотите обращаться к переменной базового класса - зачем ее тогда вообще там объявлять? Объявите в базовом виртуальные методы, реализуйте их в дочернем. Что-то мне подсказывает что вы в общем не правильно понимаете как сделать архитектуру, то есть не должно быть ситуаций, когда их базового класса вам требуется доступ к переменным производного.

Comment: //функции для работы с fooList; (я здесь указал, что в базовом классе работа с fooList ведется). Если я, например, в Bar создам функцию Clear() с очисткой списка fooList, я не хочу создавать такую же в классе BarEx, BarEx2 и т.д.

Comment: Родительский класс не знает и не должен знать обо всех своих дочерних классах. Так как в дочерних классах у вас переменные уже других типов (каких - это уже не проблема родителя) то и функция очистки должна быть переопределена в каждом дочернем отдельно.

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю, но все же надеялся, что у меня просто пробелы в знаниях и решение все-таки есть. И без необходимости дублировать функции.

Comment: @GrieVeR-13 Можно и без дублирования. См. дополнение к моему ответу. Но и там свои подводные камни.